# Oracle: What is the difference between = and in with one option?

Tags: sql, oracle

So, here are two statements which return the same results.

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE ID = 1;
-----------------------
SELECT * FROM USER WHERE ID IN (1);
```

Sometimes it's easier to generate the second query from a single item, with the option of adding additional items to the list.

Is there any inherent risks in using a single-item list in Oracle? Is it likely to cause performance issues?

Comment: in operator is just a syntax sugar (in case when subquery is not used)

Comment: AFIAK there is some internal limit number fields for in operator. Where you're bellow this limit the optimizer even does not see this operator, this sees the query rewritten as sequence of disjunctions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two queries you have shown have no difference except the syntax. Compare the explain plan:

**Query 1:**

```
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT * FROM dual WHERE dummy = 'X';

Explained.

SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 272002086

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| DUAL |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("DUMMY"='X')

13 rows selected.
```

**Query 2:**

```
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT * FROM dual WHERE dummy IN 'X';

Explained.

SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 272002086

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| DUAL |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("DUMMY"='X')

13 rows selected.
```

In both the queries, internally the filter applied is **filter("DUMMY"='X')**.

However, when you have multiple values int he **IN list**, then Oracle internally interprets as multiple **OR** conditions.

**IN list**

```
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT * FROM dual WHERE dummy IN ('X', 'Y', 'Z');

Explained.

SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 272002086

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| DUAL |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("DUMMY"='X' OR "DUMMY"='Y' OR "DUMMY"='Z')

13 rows selected.
```

You can see that Oracle internally interprets it as **filter("DUMMY"='X' OR "DUMMY"='Y' OR "DUMMY"='Z')**

Comment: So I think what you're saying is that there is little or no overhead to using a single-item list, and Oracle will sanitise the query before running it?

Comment: with multiple values in the IN list will only increase the OR conditions, it means Oracle needs to look for more data which matches the OR conditions. For a single value, there is no difference at all.